# Показать забинженные сочетания клавиш на кнопках

Tags: c#, wpf

Подскажите, вот у меня в окне есть кнопки, которые нажимаются руками и на них весят команды.

Так же, на самом окне висят InputBindings, которые вызывают те же команды, что и на кнопках.

Проблема в том, чтобы как-то отобразить для пользователя доступные ему сочетания клавиш.

Как можно решить данную проблему?

Самый простой вариант - это добавить окно с легендой.

Но какие еще есть варианты, которые могут быть удобными и более симпатичными?

Comment: Это вопрос про дизайн или техничку? Нужно больше деталей

Comment: Почему бы не Tooltip? Visual Studio делает именно так: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGFSs.png

Comment: @VladD да, мысль. А можно их как-то захокеить? Чтобы я нажимал сочетание и они тут же появлялись на против всех кнопок, где они есть?

Comment: В Word'е, кстати, при нажатии ALT вот такие подсказки открываются https://prnt.sc/115hqcm

Comment: Запросто! Можно использовать `AccessText`, в частности, его (неявно) использует `Menu` и `Label`:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gzl0C.gif. А ещё есть [свойство `RecognizesAccessKey`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/how-to-create-a-control-that-has-an-access-key-and-text-wrapping?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

Comment: Попробуйте добавить подменю в меню File и нажмите Alt + F.